# Let websocket clients subscribe, only if there's an endpoint for that channel

Tags: java, spring

In my spring boot app, I have the following websocket controller:

```
@Controller
public class QuoteController {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @SubscribeMapping("/quote/{symbol}")
    public void singleQuote(@DestinationVariable("symbol") String symbol, Principal user) {
        System.out.println("Salam");
    }

}
```

I would like the clients to be able to subscribe to a channel, only if there exists an endpoint like above for that channel. Apparently (based on the logs in the browser) clients can subscribe to any arbitrary channel.

(and btw, isn't this a bad practice to let clients to subscribe to any channel? Specially security wise. Malicious clients can subscribe to millions of channel and cause the server to slow down, or subscribe to channels that are for internal use only)

Comment: how are you creating these channels in your application?

Comment: Can't it be as simple as your server having an endpoint to return available channels and then the client code can only use those channels to subscribe ?

Comment: It can be, but it doesn't enforce the client to only subscribe to those channels.

Comment: From the top of head, did you try to make an interceptor for whitelist? Take request and fail it before it reaches the subscribe interceptor?

Comment: About security: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/wls/JMSRA/GUID-B195FCD8-7E19-4417-8B72-26D0778A987C.htm#JMSRA7714 this doc states that you have to secure it with spring security at least ;)